# Is it correct to say I came by car today?

Tags: expressions

Is it correct to say I came by car?

I work in the centre of Sydney where there are not enough car parking. So, i and my colleagues often talk about how they came to work.

Is it correct to say
I came by car today. I drove to work. I got to work by car.

Or any other suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Did you do any research? Like Googling "I came by car"?

Comment: I remember this question from my school years and the grammar book saying "I came in my car."

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is correct.

We can say 'I came here **by car**' or 'I came here **in my car**'.

We can use **by** to say how we travel. We use **by + noun** without a/an/the/my/his etc.

by car, by train, by bus, by boat etc.

I came here **by** car. I came here **by** train.

We cannot use *by* if we say my car, his car, the bus, the train etc. *In* is used for cars and taxis. *On* is used for bus, train etc.

I came here **in** my car. I travelled **on** the train.